# How do I get a WinAPI HWnd in a FireMonkey application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe

We have written a FireMonkey application using Delphi XE8.

In a Delphi 2010 VCL application I'd pass `Application.Handle` and it worked perfectly.

We are trying to send an email using MAPI, but we are getting a compile error on `Application.Handle`.

The code:

```
MAPIModule:=LoadLibrary(PChar(MAPIDLL));
If MAPIModule=0 then
  Result:=-1
else
  try
    @SM:=GetProcAddress(MAPIModule,'MAPISendMail');
    If @SM<>nil then
    begin      
      Result:=SM(0,Application.Handle,Email_message,MAPI_DIALOG or MAPI_LOGON_UI,0);
```

The compile error is: Undeclared identifier: 'Handle'

If I hover over 'Application' in the code, I see `Application - FMX.Forms.TApplication`, and if I hover over the 'Handle' it says `TApplication does not have a member named 'Handle'`.

Comment: I have used this in other places of my FMX app, which replaces the VCL use of Application.Handle. That might solve your problem: `WindowHandleToPlatform(Application.MainForm.Handle).Wnd`

Comment: @Hans, that should be the answer!

Comment: Confusingly `Application.Handle` is a HWnd, not a HModule like you'd expect: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Handle